# Magic square $29\times29$: Linear Congruences and Uniform Step Method

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm, magic-square

This linear congruency I was given is part 1 to a 2 part question, I was able to get this.
[
\begin{split}
                    14\cdot27(x+y)\equiv14\cdot16&\pmod{29}\Longrightarrow\\
                    x+y\equiv21&\pmod{29}\Longrightarrow\\
                    y\equiv21-x&\pmod{29}
                \end{split}
]
The question also includes these congruences that ultimately creates the Magic Square using [Uniform Step Method](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-04/S0002-9939-1951-0043813-X/S0002-9939-1951-0043813-X.pdf)

\begin{split}
                    x_j\equiv16+17\cdot j+23\cdot \left[\frac{j}{29} \right]\pmod{29}\\
                    y_j\equiv9+10\cdot j+4\cdot \left[\frac{j}{29} \right]\pmod{29}\\
                \end{split}
The part I am confused on the part where the question asks what the value of $j$ would be when placed in the cell with coordinates $(21,20)$ (the $x$-axis starts with $0$ and ends with $28$ and same rule applies to the $y$-axis) with these congruences and how the solved linear congruence has a relation to these congruences.

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't realize that the uniform step method was recognized when dealing with Magic Squares. Thank you for the feedback, I made an edit. Do you also happen to understand how to go about this question, I am still confused.

Comment: Do you know the alternative "De la Loubere" [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_method) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes I do, can this method be applied to this question?

Comment: I am wondering if the "De la Loubere method" doesn't, at least in certain cases, the same magic square as your "Uniform Step" method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're being asked to do is to solve the system of simultaneous congruences
$$
21\equiv16+17j+23\left[{j\over29}\right]\pmod{29};\qquad
20\equiv9+10j+4\left[{j\over29}\right]\pmod{29}
$$
I'll rewrite these as
$$
17j+23k\equiv5\pmod{29};\qquad10j+4k\equiv11\pmod{29};\qquad k=\left[{j\over29}\right]
$$
By the usual methods of solving two linear equations in two unknowns, and of solving linear congruences in one variable, we get $j\equiv12\pmod{29}$, $k\equiv9\pmod{29}$. Combining these, we can take $j=9\cdot29+12=273$.